# Counter distinct user for each days for the last 7 days with databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I want to count the number of distinct user for the last 7 days for each days.

I have the following line of codes:

```
days = lambda i: i * 86400

df1 = sc.parallelize(
  [
    ['2021-05-01','aaa'], 
    ['2021-05-08','aaa'], 
    ['2021-05-15','aaa'], 
    ['2021-05-15','bbb'], 
    ['2021-06-01','aaa'], 
    ['2021-06-10','bbb'],
    ['2021-06-25','aaa'], 
    ['2021-06-30','aaa'], 
    ['2021-07-01','bbb'], 
    ['2021-07-10','aaa'],
    ['2021-07-14','bbb'], 
    ['2021-07-15','bbb'], 
    ['2021-07-25','bbb'], 
    ['2021-07-30','bbb'],
  ]).toDF(("date", "userId"))

df1.printSchema()

df1 = df1.withColumn("date", f.to_date("date", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

df1 = (df1
       .select('date', 'userId')
       .withColumn('7_days_active_users', f.approx_count_distinct('userId').over(Window.orderBy(f.col('date').cast('long')).rangeBetween(-days(7), 0)))
      )

df1.show()
```

This is the output:

```
+----------+------+-------------------+
|      date|userId|7_days_active_users|
+----------+------+-------------------+
|2021-05-01|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-05-08|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-05-15|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-05-15|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-06-01|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-06-10|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-06-25|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-06-30|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-07-01|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-07-10|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-07-14|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-07-15|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-07-25|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-07-30|   bbb|                  2|
```

For the `2021-05-08` their should be only one distinct user.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Would you be against looping through each row then appending a list for the active users column?

Comment: I'm not against anything ;p. Also I'd like to understand why my query is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to order the window by unix timestamps of `date` column. If so, then casting DateType to LongType will result to *null*, thus gave you the result above.

Try to convert the column `date` to timestamps first using `unix_timestamp` function or `.cast('timestamp')` method before casting it to LongType.

```
w = (Window
     .orderBy(f.col('date').cast('timestamp').cast('long'))
     .rangeBetween(-days(7), 0))

df1 = (df1
       .select('date', 'userId')
       .withColumn('7_days_active_users', 
                   f.approx_count_distinct('userId').over(w))
       )
df1.show()

+----------+------+-------------------+
|      date|userId|7_days_active_users|
+----------+------+-------------------+
|2021-05-01|   aaa|                  1|
|2021-05-08|   aaa|                  1|
|2021-05-15|   aaa|                  2|
|2021-05-15|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-06-01|   aaa|                  1|
|2021-06-10|   bbb|                  1|
|2021-06-25|   aaa|                  1|
|2021-06-30|   aaa|                  1|
|2021-07-01|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-07-10|   aaa|                  1|
|2021-07-14|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-07-15|   bbb|                  2|
|2021-07-25|   bbb|                  1|
|2021-07-30|   bbb|                  1|
+----------+------+-------------------+
```